# Prove that the torus is a regular subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the inclusion of the torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$, prove that the torus is a regular subvariety.

I have the next idea.
 If we describe de points of the torus as pairs $(u,v)$. We have to prove that the following map, for fixed $r,R>0$ is bijective, continous and opened (or closed). (That's called *incrustación* in Spanish, I don't know how to say in English)

$$(u,v)\mapsto((R+r\cos(u))\cos(v),(R+r\cos(u))\sin(v),r\sin(u))$$

Am I right?

Comment: And...? Have you tried anything? Which definition of the torus are you referring to? Same for regular subvariety.

Comment: Sorry, I will write my approche

Comment: Does a subvariety mean it must be the zero set of a collection of one or more polynomial functions in $x,y,z$? If so it looks like using cosine and sine might need some more details to get back to $x,y,z$.